# at com.hangroo.MainActivity1.onCreate(MainActivity1.java:53)

Tags: android

I have new error now after  resizing the layouts and its components and I have error in setcontent view locating by logcat on clicking the line
 
`08-10 11:56:36.845: E/AndroidRuntime(29204):    at com.hangroo.MainActivity1.onCreate(MainActivity1.java:53)` 
in logcat . following is logcat

```
08-10 12:14:59.845: D/OpenGLRenderer(29839): Enabling debug mode 0
08-10 12:15:01.145: D/AndroidRuntime(29839): Shutting down VM
08-10 12:15:01.145: W/dalvikvm(29839): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x416adc08)
08-10 12:15:01.165: E/AndroidRuntime(29839): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-10 12:15:01.165: E/AndroidRuntime(29839): Process: com.hangroo, PID: 29839
08-10 12:15:01.165: E/AndroidRuntime(29839): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.hangroo/com.hangroo.MainActivity1}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #90: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
08-10 12:15:01.165: E/AndroidRuntime(29839):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2339)
08-10 12:15:01.165: E/AndroidRuntime(29839):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2391)
08-10 12:15:01.165: E/AndroidRuntime(29839):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:166)
08-10 12:15:01.165: E/AndroidRuntime(29839):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1281)
08-10 12:15:01.165: E/AndroidRuntime(29839):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-10 12:15:01.165: E/AndroidRuntime(29839):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
08-10 12:15:01.165: E/AndroidRuntime(29839):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5511)
08-10 12:15:01.165: E/AndroidRuntime(29839):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-10 12:15:01.165: E/AndroidRuntime(29839):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-10 12:15:01.165: E/AndroidRuntime(29839):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
08-10 12:15:01.165: E/AndroidRuntime(29839):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
08-10 12:15:01.165: E/AndroidRuntime(29839):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-10 12:15:01.165: E/AndroidRuntime(29839): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #90: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
08-10 12:15:01.165: E/AndroidRuntime(29839):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getLayoutDimension(TypedArray.java:492)
08-10 12:15:01.165: E/AndroidRuntime(29839):    at android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.setBaseAttributes(ViewGroup.java:6199)
08-10 12:15:01.165: E/AndroidRuntime(29839):    at android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.<init>(ViewGroup.java:6368)
08-10 12:15:01.165: E/AndroidRuntime(29839):    at android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams.<init>(LinearLayout.java:1837)
08-10 12:15:01.165: E/AndroidRuntime(29839):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.generateLayoutParams(LinearLayout.java:1749)
08-10 12:15:01.165: E/AndroidRuntime(29839):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.generateLayoutParams(LinearLayout.java:58)
08-10 12:15:01.165: E/AndroidRuntime(29839):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:768)
08-10 12:15:01.165: E/AndroidRuntime(29839):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
08-10 12:15:01.165: E/AndroidRuntime(29839):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
08-10 12:15:01.165: E/AndroidRuntime(29839):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
08-10 12:15:01.165: E/AndroidRuntime(29839):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
08-10 12:15:01.165: E/AndroidRuntime(29839):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:366)
08-10 12:15:01.165: E/AndroidRuntime(29839):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2009)
08-10 12:15:01.165: E/AndroidRuntime(29839):    at com.hangroo.MainActivity1.onCreate(MainActivity1.java:53)
08-10 12:15:01.165: E/AndroidRuntime(29839):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5322)
08-10 12:15:01.165: E/AndroidRuntime(29839):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
08-10 12:15:01.165: E/AndroidRuntime(29839):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2303)
08-10 12:15:01.165: E/AndroidRuntime(29839):    ... 11 more
08-10 12:15:03.075: I/Process(29839): Sending signal. PID: 29839 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would have bothered to read the complete logcat error, you could have seen the error on your own.

```
08-10 12:15:01.165: E/AndroidRuntime(29839): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.hangroo/com.hangroo.MainActivity1}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #90: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
```

It clearly says **line #90: You must supply a layout_width attribute.**

Go to the layout file you are using in Activity `com.hangroo.MainActivity1` and add the `layout_width` attribute in the element.